# Validação de parametros de URL

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net

Gostaria de opiniões sobre uma questão, talvez até simples, apenas para saber mais formas de fazer isso. A situação é a seguinte:

OBS: utilizo neste exemplo .Net Framework 4.0 com muito Javascript, só uso Code-Behind para pegar os `QueryStrings` e armazená-los em `input hidden's`, toda a regra de negocio é feita em um *web service* (.amx).

01- Você envia um id = 1 para uma pagina de edição ao clicar no link.

```
< a href="http://site/editar.aspx?IdPessoa=1" >Editar< /a >
```

02- Na pagina **editar.aspx** através do Code-Behind você joga num `input hidden` (`txtIdPessoa`):

```
this.txtIdPessoa.Value = (Request.QueryString["IdPessoa"] ?? string.Empty).Trim();
```

03- Nesta página **editar.aspx** tem os outros campos para edição da pessoa. Depois que a pessoa preenche todos os campos ela vai salvar, feito através de *jquery ajax*, enviando os valores para um método (`SalvarDados()`) de um *web service*:

```
$("#btnSalvar").click(function(){
        $.ajax({
            type: "POST",
            url: "http://site/WebService1.asmx/SalvarDados",
            data: "{'idpessoa':'" + $("#txtIdPessoa").val() + "','nome':'" + $("#txtNomePessoa").val()  + "'}",
            contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
            dataType: "json",
            success: function (resposta) {
        alert("Sucesso");
            },
            error: function (xhr, msg, e) {
        alert("Erro");
            }
        });
});
```

04- Mas você pode dar uma burlada ai, se antes de clicar em salvar você digitar na url o código abaixo:

```
javascript:$("#txtIdPessoa").val("2");
```

05- Ao salvar, você vai fazer a edição para outra pessoa, de `Id = 2`, a dúvida é como armazenar este `IdPessoa`, sem que possa ser alterado desta forma? Como vocês usam?

06- Há validações no cliente e no servidor, aqui apenas postei de forma simples, o problema é que este script não da *refresh* na página.

Comment: Cara, dá uma lida na [help] e em [como fazer uma boa pergunta](http://pt.stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1 - Eu usaria GUID ao invez de INT, só isso já resolveria **todos** os problemas.

2 - Se você guardar na session ou ViewState, o usuário não pode alterar no Client.

Session["IdPessoa] = Request.QueryString["IdPessoa"];

3 - Passa o valor da SESSION e nao do input Hidden.

4 - Se estiver na Session/ViewState não tem como alterar.

5 - Não entendi

6 - Não entendi muito bem.

Comment: Opa Paulo, valew por responder, 

Eu tinha pensado em usar tanto GUID como session, o meu sistema vai ter uma grande quantidade de tabelas e registros.

O GUID usa 16 bytes enquanto o int usa apenas 4. Mas talvez não aumente tanto o espaço usado pelo banco. Talvez esta seja a melhor opção neste caso, eliminando o item 5.


Obg, abraços